# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.com.packt.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a project with Spring Initializr in Maven, Java 17, Spring boot 3.0.0 with two dependencies : Spring Web and Spring Boot DevTools

i tried to run the main class and i have this error :

```
Erreur : impossible to find or charge the principal class src.main.java.com.packt.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication
caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.com.packt.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication
```

I did change nothing in the code can you explain me the error please thanks you very much

---

CardatabaseApplication.java :

```
package com.packt.cardatabase;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CardatabaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CardatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

> Now, if the project was executed correctly, you should see the started CardatabaseApplication class in the text at the end of the console. The following screenshot shows the content of the Eclipse console after our Spring Boot project has been started: "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBt1h.png

That is the screen of my IDE tell me what do you wanna see i screen again

Answer (score 0):

Two things indicate to the real issue:

- The class `CardatabaseApplication` is defined in the `com.packt.cardatabase` database.
- This error message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.com.packt.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication`.

Somehow, you need to remove `src.main.java` when you are running the class. I assume you are running this from your IDE, and a misconfiguration is causing this.

Comment: what do you mean by remove src.main.java ?

Comment: delete the path ?

Comment: i run this on eclipse and i click on CardatabaseApplication.java before run

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your IDE? The visuals can reveal your configuration.

Comment: i posted 15 mins ago you can see on the post

Comment: on god i tried on intellij this is working wtf eclipse